# Uh oh. We have a [beginner] tag!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I noticed that we have the [beginner](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tag. Does anyone have any objections to it being edited out?

The beginner tag is currently discouraged across all sites, please see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for the reason.

Also, what about [robots](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robots)?

(Both are small enough and can be hand-detagged, but I want some community opinion first. Also post any other bad tags you come across here)

Answer (score 8):

Given that ["From this point on, meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) I would suggest that we get rid of both of these meta-tags before people get used to using them.

In addition, all questions *should* be about robotics, so the [robots](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robots) tag should never be appropriate. The narrower tags like [mobile-robot](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-robot), [industrial-robot](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrial-robot) and [wheeled-robot](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wheeled-robot) are all fine though.

Comment: I just did `[beginner]`. We'll do the other one a bit later, don't wanna flood the main page.

Comment: @Manishearth I also tidied up `[tag:robots]`.

Comment: Perhaps the same goes with `[tag:research]`?