# Is the Beginner tag back?

Tags: discussion, tags

As a follow on question from the 2012 [Uh oh. We have a [beginner] tag!](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/uh-oh-we-have-a-beginner-tag), I’ve noticed a couple of the meta tags discussed for deletion are still being used. Was this intentional or have they crept back into use somehow?  Examples (see below) `beginner` and `research`.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh oh.  Thanks for bringing this to our attention.  I was unaware that we discouraged meta-tags.  I'll keep an eye out from now on.  I'm sure these just slowly creep back in as users add them.

Can anyone think of any other robotics specific meta-tags that we should discourage?

Edit:

I went through and deleted most of the "beginner" tags.  But there are some closed questions that have *only* the beginner tag.  I can't think of any other tag that fits because the question is basically like: "I am a beginner, what should I do?".

Is it worth keeping these tags around and putting **"DO NOT USE THIS TAG"** in the tag wiki?  Then the tags can be "watched" and quickly dealt with.  Or is removing all instances of the tag better because their non-existence might discourage their use?

Comment: If a tag that is never appropriate keeps getting recreated over and over again, it might eventually be worth requesting that the CMs block/blacklist the tag. Relevant MSE post: [What is a blocked tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295148/335251), [How do we request to have a tag blocked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/335251)

Answer (score 1):

I've now edited the tags on those old closed questions, so no questions now have the [beginner](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tag.

I tried creating a [meta-tags-are-discouraged](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags-are-discouraged) and making [beginner](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) a tag synonym of it, but that didn't seem to prevent the [beginner](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tag being added to posts, so I think we just have to keep an eye out for [beginner](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tags and remove them when we see them.